# How do I copy characters from one string to another string?

Tags: c

I have a problem, I am programming in C and it turns out that I am copying some characters from one string to another but I do it manually, you know with a function that it creates, but I want to know if there is any standard C function that allows me to do that, I will put An example so you can understand what I'm trying to say:

```
char str1[] = "123copy321";
char str2[5];

theFunctionINeed(str1, str2, 3, 6);   //Copy from str1[3] to str1[6]

printf("%s\n", str1);
printf("%s\n", str2);
```

and the result would be:

```
123copy321
copy
```

I hope you can help me, thank you

Comment: There are a plethora of options: `strncpy()`, `memmove()`, `memcpy()` could all be used very easily.  There are probably others.  You'd have to be careful to null terminate the copied string with all of those.

Comment: @SupportUkraine – given the context, it seems to mean "copy the characters between `str1[3]` and `str1[6]` (inclusive) into `str2` (and null terminate the copy)".

Comment: haha maybe I should specify more what the function does, but I thought you could understand it from the context

Comment: You're looking for a C-language [substring()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/substring-in-cpp/) function.  There are many ways to accomplish this; there are several caveats you need to be aware if regardless of which solution you choose.  Here's a good place to start: https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pointer arithmetic and the function [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str1[] = "123copy321";
    char str2[5];

    //copy str1[3] up to and including str1[6] to str2
    memcpy( str2, str1 + 3, 4 );

    //add terminating null character to str2
    str2[4] = '\0';

    printf( "%s\n", str1 );
    printf( "%s\n", str2 );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
123copy321
copy
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot that the function `strncpy` is intended for fixed-length strings and not intended for use with null-terminated strings. I have therefore stopped using that function and am using `memcpy` instead.

Comment: The `strncpy()` function can be used as effectively as `memcpy()` or `memmove()` to copy 4 bytes; but none of them null terminates the string.  The one advantage of `strncpy()` over the other two is that it will stop copying at a null byte (after assigning it), so if the string being copied ends before the number of bytes specified, it won't read beyond the end of the string.  But when the string to be copied is bigger than the number of bytes to be copied, the three are essentially equivalent.  None of them checks that the string to be copied is at least as long as the first offset.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel -  You have helped me a lot, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

With `theFunctionINeed(str1, str2, 3, 6);` there are a number of issues:

1. Source string may be less than 3.
2. Available sub-string length may be less than 4.
3. Destination array may be too small.
4. Unusual to pass in the first and last index to copy.  This prevents forming a zero-length sub-string.  More idiomatic to pass in beginning and 1) length or 2) index of one-past.
5. How about returning something useful, like was the destination big enough?

Alternative untested sample code follows. `restrict` means the two pointers should not point to overlapping memory.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Return `destination` when large enough
// otherwise return NULL when `size` was too small. 
bool SubString(size_t destination_size, char *restrict destination,
    const char *restrict source, size_t offset, size_t length) {
  if (destination_size == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  destination[0] = '\0';

  // Quickly search for the null character among the first `offset` characters of the source.
  if (memchr(source, '\0', offset)) {
    return destination;
  }

  destination_size--;
  size_t destination_length = length <= destination_size ? length : destination_size;
  strncat(destination, source + offset, destination_length);
  return length <= destination_size ? destination : NULL;
}
```